# Perforce - How to completely sync a folder with remote depot

Tags: perforce

I'm new to Perforce. I have reorganized my project's folder structure by moving some folders into other folders. It's like:

```
// original structure
/Folder_A
/Folder_B
```

```
// structure after modification
/Folder_A/Folder_B
```

The issue is that when my coworker trying get latest, he retrived newly updated folder structure while keeps all older data untouched:

```
// structure after my coworker hit get latest in p4v
/Folder_A/Folder_B
/Folder_B
```

I have to admit this situation is kind of expected and this behavior acutally keeps my local generated files (binaries, intermediate files, etc.) not cleared by get latest operation. However, in this 'folder structure reorg' scenario, I do want everything to be 1 to 1 match to the depot, nothing more and nothing less.

I've tried get revision with force operation combo on my /Content folder where I'm doing reorg, and it didn't do the jobs completely: All files in Folder_B did go away, but all subdirectories and Folder_B itself kept existing, leaving a bunch of empty folders.
So I'm wondering if I'm in a wrong workflow? Do I miss something? Or the answer is simply delete them manually? (Which seems to be cumbersome and error-prone especially for my non tech background coworker.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check his workspace settings. I suspect it's set at "normdir" and I suspect what you want is "rmdir" which will automatically delete empty directories.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, check in your workspace settings and turn on the rmdir feature in order to auto delete those empty directories. (I always have that setting turned on in my template workspace so that it is on by default in New workspaces)
However, this won't fix your existing workspaces. You will need to delete Folder_B manually in your current workspace. But that should fix it for the future.

Also, it is important to know that any files that are Ignored will not be deleted or moved, because version control will not touch them at all.